# How to send Mandrill message with special characters?

Tags: php, special-characters, mandrill

I am using Mandrill to send mails to our members.
Sending a normal text message works perfect.
But a message with special characters (ä,ë,ï,ö,ü,€,...) will not be attached in Mandrill's `'html' =>` variable.

Can anyone tell me how to send a message with special characters through Mandrill?

I tried to edit the `$message_content` variable with `str_replace` and `preg_replace`, none worked so far.

When I use `&iuml;` and `&euro;` when typing the message content, it works perfect. But I can't seem to change this when the submit button is pressed.

this is my code:

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $from_name = $_POST['from_name'];
    $from_email = $_POST['from_email'];
    $message_content = nl2br($_POST['message_content']);
    $mail_to_members = array();
    $mail_to_members[] = array('email' => 'name@domain.com');
    $mail_to_members[] = array('email' => 'name@domain.com');

    //Get Mandrill API
    require_once './include/src/Mandrill.php'; 
    $mandrill = new Mandrill('API-key');

    //Create mail
    $message = array(
        'subject' => $subject,
        'from_name' => $from_name,
        'from_email' => $from_email,
        'html' => $message_content,
        'to' => $mail_to_members,
    );

    $mandrill->messages->send($message);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had this exact same problem and we solved it using the following:

```
mb_convert_encoding($message_content, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII');
```

It converts your content from ASCII to UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

Try using [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

It will convert all special characters to HTML entities.

For example:

```
<?php
$string = 'ä - ë - ï - ö - ü - €';
echo htmlentities($string);
```

Will outout:

```
&auml; - &euml; - &iuml; - &ouml; - &uuml; - &euro;
```

Any HTML parser that follow the standard will be able to display them.

Comment: unfortunately this does not work when I change my code to this:
`$message_content_POST = nl2br($_POST['message_content']);
$message_content= htmlentities($message_content_POST);`

Comment: What is the output of `$message_content`? And do you get error?

Comment: If I send some text with a special character the output is empty.
I do get an error `stderr: PHP message: PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set in .../src/Mandrill.php on line 68` But I also get this error when I send a normal message...

Comment: When I echo this: `$string = 'ä - ë - ï - ö - ü - €'; echo htmlentities($string);` The output is the same as the input `ä - ë - ï - ö - ü - €` is this depending on the PHP version? I have PHP version 5.4.37

Comment: You should expect this when running this using a browser. Check the **browser html source** and not the output.

Comment: Then it still makes no sense that it returns an empty string. any other solution?

Comment: Yes this works, and any other normal message works as well, as long as there are no special characters in it.