# Mandrill Api ?? in Subject

Tags: email, cakephp, mandrill

I'm using the Mandrill Transport (https://github.com/khanlou/MandrillTransport-CakePHP) to send mails in my cakephp application.

But when sending mails I get ?? in odd places in my subject line due to special characters.

Subject = '*Découvrez vite toutes les nouveautés sur r7site.com*'

Result = '*Découvrez vite toutes les nouveautés sur r7?? site.com*'

As you can see the ?? are placed very strangely.

When I'm using the default cakephp mail it works like a charm...

```
public $default = array(
    'transport' => 'Mail',
    'from' => 'noreply@q8mazout.be',
    'charset' => 'utf-8',
    'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
);
```

I guess it has something to do with the utf-8 charset, but I'm not sure. The content works fine with mandrill and actually the chars are printed fine as well in the subject. Just the ?? should not be there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Apparently CakePHP adds new line characters to the title causing the title to break. Although it only occurred with special characters.

debug of the title:

> '=?UTF-8?B?RMOpY291dnJleiB2aXRlIHRvdXRlcyBsZXMgbm91dmVhdXTDqXMgc3VyIHE4?=
>   =?UTF-8?B?bWF6b3V0LmJl?='

solution in the MandrillTestTransport

```
$subject = str_replace(array(PHP_EOL, "\r"), '', $this->_cakeEmail->subject());

$message = array(
    'html' => $this->_cakeEmail->message('html'),
    'text' => $this->_cakeEmail->message('text'),
    'subject' => $subject,
    ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your content from ASCII to UTF-8, and for this you can use below function for this because special characters is many time not supported by some of the third party apis like mandrill.

mb_convert_encoding($subject, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII');

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Not working though...

Title now : DÃ©couvrez vite toutes les nouveautÃ©s su?? r site.com

Comment: I see this stackoverflow question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206544/how-to-send-mandrill-message-with-special-characters

but it's for the content and there I have no problem?